# Undefined Image src in popup Model Box

Tags: javascript

I'm making a Image Gallery with model popup box, The JavaScript code is working, but Undefined Image src of the gallery popup modal box and popup image not showing in content box. What mistake i did? Any Help is Greatly Appreciated, thanks.

```
<?php echo '<img id="myImg" src="'.esc_url( $info['0'] ).'" onclick="imgPopup();" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">'; ?>


function imgPopup(){
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("myImg1");
modal.style.display = "block";
modalImg.src = this.src;

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
span.onclick = function() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
} }
```

Comment: Why down vote please comment

Comment: Please Comment I can improve my question I'm beginner in JavaScript.

Comment: `this` inside your function is not what you think it is. (Simply logging it to the browser console using `console.log(this)` could have easily shown you that.) https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-this-event-handlers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
<?php echo '<img id="myImg" src="'.esc_url( $info['0'] ).'" onclick="imgPopup(this);" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">'; ?>

function imgPopup(elem){
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("myImg1");

    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = elem.src;

    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    span.onclick = function() { 
        modal.style.display = "none";
    } 
}
```

Comment: I have multiple images I need get dynamic way to image src.